# Copy a local git branch from one working copy to another

Tags: git

I have a few local branches containing experimental work. For a reason unrelated to git, i must have several working copies of the same remote. How can i duplicate the local branches in other working copies without pushing them to the remote?

The branches need not remain synchronized i.e. i'm not expecting to be able to see my commits appear in other working copies after duplicating the branches. I know i can just copy the contents to a new local branch in the target working copy, but is there a way to import the commits too?

Comment: You mean duplicating the local branch or full local repository?

Comment: I mean duplicating the local branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit to add prefix note: I came into this thinking (for some reason) that you were considering all this from the server side.  If you're on the *client* side, remember, you can clone a clone, or use `git worktree add` to make multiple work-trees.  If you create multiple repositories on one machine (e.g., on your own laptop or deskside system), you can `git fetch` from one to another: just keep in mind the way that Git renames branches when you run `git fetch`.  You can `git push` from one to another as well; but keep in mind that `git push` *doesn't* rename anything.

(The worktree method is much nicer for this kind of usage.  It's good if your Git is 2.6+ since there were a few bugs fixed shortly after the first release of `git worktree` in 2.5.)

---

> How can i duplicate the local branches in other working copies without pushing them to the remote?

Do you mean "duplicate the work-tree contents" (in which case the answer is "use an archive utility"), or do you mean "duplicate the commits" (in which case the answer is more complicated)?

> ... but is there a way to import the commits too?

Yes: it's called `git push`. :-)

Seriously, if you get not only the files, but also the commits, you have the history, because the history *is* the commits.  If you have the history, you might as well store it in a repository.  If you have the repository, you might as well use `git push` to update it.  So why *not* do that?  Note that there's no constraint that a server that has a repository have only *one* clone of that repository.  If there's some reason to keep a "clean clone" along with a "testing" one (or several), you can just make multiple repositories.

You can also, since Git 2.5, use `git worktree add` to make multiple work-trees for a single repository.  The normal constraint here is that each work-tree must be on its own independent branch; but be careful if you combine this with either a bare server, or with a non-bare `receive.denyCurrentBranch = updateInstead` server, as the receive side of `git push` only detects issues with pushes to the primary work-tree, i.e., the one not added with `git worktree add`.  It's just not clever even to perform the `updateInstead` action on extra work-trees, so they misbehave in the same way that forced the existence of `receive.denyCurrentBranch` in the first place.

---

In all cases, remember that a branch name is simply a *pointer to a commit*.  There is nothing tying a commit to any one branch: many commits are often on many branches.  In a typical repository, the root commit is on *every* branch.  A branch name just serves two purposes: (1) to identify the *tip commit* of that branch (from which we find earlier commits), and (2) to protect the tip commit and all commits reachable *from* the tip commit.  The protection in (2) is from the Grim <strike>Reaper</strike> Collector, `git gc`: the garbage collector.  The job of `git gc` is to delete, from the repository, any temporary objects—including temporary commits—that have outlived their usefulness.  The fact that a commit can be reached from some external name—any name will do, so tags count as well here, for instance—indicates that the commit is useful and should not be discarded.

Comment: The git worktree add looks like what i'm looking for.